# I want to transfer data from AWS to my physical computer using scp command

Tags: ssh, scp, aws

My AWS server has public IP address `a.b.c.d` and my computer has private IP address 192.168.1.25 and public IP address `x.y.z.t` How do I transfer data using scp command?

Comment: Please remove those IP addresses. That's sensitive information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From local computer...

```
scp REMOTE_USER@REMOTE_IP:/path/to/file /path/to/local/directory
```

For more information, `man scp`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use rsync, as long as your server runs sshd and is configured properly:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync
`